# DQL subquery - is already defined

Tags: doctrine-query, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to reuse the definition name "comments" - table Comments (AppBundle:Comments entity) in the 5th DQL subquery, but I get the error: `"Error: 'comments' is already defined."`

Here is the DQL query:

```
  SELECT employer.name AS employer_name, employer.position AS employer_position, employer.id AS employer_id,

                (SELECT company.company_name FROM Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User company WHERE company.id = employer.company) AS company_name,
                (SELECT city.name FROM AppBundle:City city WHERE city.id = employer.city) AS city_name,
                (SELECT MAX(comments.id) FROM AppBundle:Comments comments WHERE comments.employer = employer_id) AS comment_id,
                (SELECT commenttype.name FROM AppBundle:CommentTypes commenttype WHERE commenttype.id = comment_id) AS comment_name,
                (SELECT COUNT(comments.id) FROM AppBundle:Comments comments WHERE comments.employer = employer_id) AS comment_count

                FROM AppBundle:Employer employer
```

How can I reuse the definition without redefining it?

I tried also with this:

```
SELECT employer.name AS employer_name, employer.position AS employer_position, employer.id AS employer_id,

                (SELECT company.company_name FROM Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User company WHERE company.id = employer.company) AS company_name,
                (SELECT city.name FROM AppBundle:City city WHERE city.id = employer.city) AS city_name,
                (SELECT MAX(comments.id) FROM AppBundle:Comments comments WHERE comments.employer = employer_id) AS comment_id,
                (SELECT commenttype.name FROM AppBundle:CommentTypes commenttype WHERE commenttype.id = comment_id) AS comment_name,
                (SELECT COUNT(comments.id) FROM comments WHERE comments.employer = employer_id) AS comment_count

                FROM AppBundle:Employer employer
```

, but now I get "Class 'comments' is not defined." error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a duplicate alias in the first query.

Try this:

SELECT employer.name AS employer_name, employer.position AS employer_position, employer.id AS employer_id,

```
            (SELECT company.company_name FROM Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User company WHERE company.id = employer.company) AS company_name,
            (SELECT city.name FROM AppBundle:City city WHERE city.id = employer.city) AS city_name,
            (SELECT MAX(comments.id) FROM AppBundle:Comments comments WHERE comments.employer = employer_id) AS comment_id,
            (SELECT commenttype.name FROM AppBundle:CommentTypes commenttype WHERE commenttype.id = comment_id) AS comment_name,
            (SELECT COUNT(aComments.id) FROM AppBundle:Comments aComments WHERE aComments.employer = employer_id) AS comment_count

            FROM AppBundle:Employer employer
```

Hope this help